# black (night mode) tiles appearing in high zoom levels of custom rastersource react-native-mapbox-gl

Tags: android, react-native, mapbox, mapbox-gl, react-native-mapbox-gl

I have developed my own maptile server and I want to use it as my raster source in react-native-mapbox-gl
this is my code:

const rasterSourceProps = {
id: 'iranMap',
tileUrlTemplates: ['http://.../{z}/{x}/{y}.png'],
tileSize: 256,

};

```
<MapboxGL.MapView   
        style={styles.map} 
        rotateEnabled>

          <MapboxGL.RasterSource {...rasterSourceProps} >
                <MapboxGL.BackgroundLayer id="background"  sourceLayerID="iranMap" style={{ backgroundColor:"#f2efea"} } />
                <MapboxGL.RasterLayer
                    id="iranMapLayer"
                    sourceLayerID="iranMap"
                    minZoomLevel= {1}
                    maxZoomLevel= {19}   
                    style={{rasterOpacity: 1, rasterFadeDuration: 100}}               
                />           
          </MapboxGL.RasterSource>
          <MapboxGL.Camera zoomLevel={3} centerCoordinate={coordinates} />
          <MapboxGL.PointAnnotation coordinate={coordinates} id="Test" />        
        </MapboxGL.MapView>
```

I can view my map with my own tiles, but the problem is that in high zoom levels, some tiles are loaded in night mode as the picture below:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1O_OQdMI-7SKCC3E5HSnuR_vwOzwseVOY/view?usp=sharing

any solutions?

Comment: I have experienced this only in debug. Have you tried testing the release version?

Comment: I've tested it only in emulator (android studio). You had the same problem as well?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem but with point images instead of tiles.

Comment: I've seen someone saying that the problem does not appear in release mode on a real device but I didn't test it myself.

Comment: What is the resolution of your tiles?

Comment: I have not set resolution, how should I do that?

Comment: What I am thinking is that your resolution is too high and the library cannot handle it.

Comment: And how should I fix it? Is there any parameter to set or something?

Comment: And the resolution problem is fixed after release in real device?

Comment: I do not think so. Try to decrease the resolution of your tiles by 2 and then test it.

Comment: Most likely but not for sure.

Comment: I mean how to decrease this resolution?

Comment: I do not think I would be able to help you because you would need to do it from the side of the tiles server, most likely. Test it first on a real device and see if it a problem. If it is still, try to decrease the tiles on the server side.

Comment: Thanks so much 

Comment: Do you have some native Android experience by any chance? I am experiencing out of memory errors when I am using high res images 512x512px with react-native-mapbox-gl points. Did you experience something like that?

Comment: I'm here to inform you that yes!!! I build my apk and viewed my map in real device and everything is correct :) thanks so much

Comment: Same thing for me, everything worked out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to develop the app in release version and view the map in real device! For me the problem is solved